# How to send pointer event from activity to window behind it?

Tags: android

I am trying to create my realization of PointerLocation-like program.

**The Question is:**
How can I send pointer event from activity to window behind it?

For example: 
I have an activity with invisible layout, so I can see main menu (etc) of my device, and I want to send all screen-touching events  of my activity to the background (main menu etc.).
Maybe someone have any idiea or solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

There's BroadcastReceiver / BroadcastManager, which would allow sending and receiving messages between applications. You can limit it to within the app. I'm sure there are other ways.

Do you really need to have a separate, invisible layout in order to pull this off though? There's quite a few listeners like onTouch()